# How to do the shape borders like this in the image attached

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

[Have a look at this image http://www.cbucn.com/uploads/201409/cc8d1ceca032a49c509328a001a899d0.jpg](http://www.cbucn.com/uploads/201409/cc8d1ceca032a49c509328a001a899d0.jpg)

I'm going to create something similar.

Circles can be made very easily.
Color Gradient can be applied easily.
Shadows are left-hand play.

But, there is something different about the edges of those circles. They are kind of think or like give us a feel of thickness. I wonder how that is done with a flat shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, they seem to just have a gradient applied to the strokes, that's all.

[image]

Although it's a bit difficult to see in the image you posted. They could just be solid strokes against the gradient fills.